# mkdir foobar with todays date and then give foobar a variables name

Tags: bash

How can I create a directory with todays date, but then give it a variable name to be used later in the script? This is what I've got at the moment -

```
mkdir "$HOME/build/emacs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%R)";
let "$HOME/build/emacs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%R)" = "$today"
```

The first line works with no problems, but I can't see how to get something like the second line working. Ultimately I will be copying files from /usr/local/bin into $HOME/build/emacs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%R) before they get overwritten by emacs being rebuilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
today="$HOME/build/emacs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%R)"
mkdir "$today"
```

If you want to copy file using the variable:

```
cp /usr/local/bin/file_to_copy "$today"/
```

Answer (score 2):

`let` is used to carry out arthritic operations on variables which does not sound like what you want. There some reference on the `let` built-in command [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/let).

Instead to assign your date based directory name to a variable you should do:

```
today="$HOME/build/emacs/$(date +%Y%m%d-%R)"
```

There some documentation on variable assignment [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html).

Having done that you can use the `today` variable wherever you need, like so:

```
mkdir "${today}"
```